# Switch from one recyclerview to another recyclerview using firebase firestore for category (Nested fields)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, categories, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a list application for companies using Kotlin and firebase. In my application, there will be 2 recyclerviews and a page showing details when clicked. What I'm trying to do is categorize foods by company names. For example, more than one meal may be requested from a company. When you click on that company, the added foods should be listed (this will be the first recyclerview). When you click on the food, the properties should be displayed.(the second recylerview)

I looked to see if there could be a nested recyclerview, but this would not be appropriate since there will not be more than one recyclerview on the same page.

How can I categorize Firebase by company name and then list the foods with that company name? How can I create nested field in firestore?

[Firestore shape that I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkeQG.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Are you looking for a database schema or code? What are you using Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.